# Meu site está dando erro no Jquery e não sei o que fazer

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap

[image: Sou novo na programação e estou desenvolvendo utilizando jquery e boostrap no wordpress. Porém ao fazer upload do tema para o servido aparece esse erro.]

Sou novo na programação e estou desenvolvendo utilizando jquery e boostrap no wordpress. Porém ao fazer upload do tema para o servido aparece esse erro.
Agradeço a atenção de quem puder ajudar desde já.

Comment: Evite prints, principalmente quando o mesmo sequer exibe algum erro...

Comment: Seja bem vindo! Quanto mais você especificar o seu problema mais fácil será de te ajudar. O seu problema é na hora de fazer o upload do tema para o wordpress certo? O wordpress exibe alguma mensagem de erro e o tema não é upado com sucesso? Qual seria o tema? Versão do wordpress?

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR;

A mensagem acima não é um erro, é só um log. Ele está dizendo que o JQMigrate foi carregado. Se for só isto, não precisa se preocupar ;)

### Explicação

Para interagir com o console do browser usa-se um objeto JS, também chamado `console`. Ele pode mandar vários 'tipos' de mensagens usados para diferentes ocasiões.

Os tipos existentes e os seus respectivos usos são:

- debug: debugar código;
- log: indicar acontecimentos relevantes;
- warn: indicar que algo fora do normal aconteceu, mas o programa continuará executando na medida do possível;
- error: indicar que um erro grave aconteceu e que pode interferir na execução do programa.

Para mandar uma mensagem com um dos tipos acima, basta usar o método com  o mesmo nome do tipo:

```js
console.debug('Testando meu código');
console.info('É bom você saber disso');
console.log('Algo relevante aconteceu');
console.warn('Algo pode estar errado');
console.error('Algo definitivamente está errado');
```

No Chrome é possível distinguir o tipo  através do ícone/cor da mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto é possível perceber que a sua mensagem é um log e portanto não é um erro.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Vou explicar: depois que ativei o tema no wordpress ele não carrega. Só aparece a mensagem que tirei print!

Comment: Fica dando erro 500. Vocês querem que eu envie o código?